# Proper use of !important in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm wondering what best practices are regarding the use of `!important` if I wanted to write a media query to give both left and right column images the same padding in the below scenario.

```
.twocolumn .left img {
    padding: 5px;
}

.twocolumn .right img {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

My two options are below.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){ 

    .twocolumn img {
        padding:0px !important;
    }
```

OR

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

    .twocolumn .left img {
    padding: 0px;
    }

    .twocolumn .right img {
    padding: 0px;
    }
}
```

Do I use `!important` to simplify the document, or do I write both full selector strings with identical values separately? In real-life applications the character savings can be much greater than in the above example. Would it still be best to avoid `!important`, or is it then justified?

Comment: your media query is backwards, then there's no need for `!important` *and* reduced duplication.

Comment: The only time you should *have* to use `!important` is if there is some CSS inserted via JavaScript or if there are inline styles, and you don't have access to where those things are happening (e.g. if you can only edit the CSS file for some reason). What really sucks is when someone uses `!important` in an inline style or inserted JS.

Comment: It is always best to avoid the `!important`. It's the herpes of CSS- using it needs it to work on everything else. The actual purpose of it is userstyles and shorthand classes (like, say, having a `.b` rule that bolds the contained text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, **never use important**. I have, in the past, thought I had come across legitimate reasons to use `!important`, and in *every* instance I have been wrong and regretted it.

So with that, you have already shown a reasonable solution:

```
.twocolumn .left img {
    padding: 5px;
}

.twocolumn .right img {
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

    .twocolumn .left img {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .twocolumn .right img {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

But of course, that's redundant, and you want to reduce duplication.

You *can* merge the two selectors into one with a `,`

```
.twocolumn .left img,
.twocolumn .right img {
  padding: 0;
}
```

But even that's longer than necessary.

In my opinion you should reverse the media query:

```
.twocolumn img {
  padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  .twocolumn .left img {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .twocolumn .right img {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

This has the benefits of:

- reduced duplication
- lower specificity for the general rule
- mobile-first approach to styling

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use !important for those media queries. They would automatically get overwritten because you're writing it in a media query. Your best option would be option 2. Option 1 is unnecessary because it would get overwritten anyway without the !important.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

   .twocolumn .left img {
    padding: 0px;
 }

   .twocolumn .right img {
    padding: 0px;
 }
```

}

Or better yet you can write it like this since both those classes are using the same rule.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px){

     .twocolumn .left img, .twocolumn .right img {
      padding: 0px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, if I don't use `!important` in the media query, it has lower specificity so does nothing, even though it's further down in the stylesheet. But I didn't realize I could write both `.twocolumn .left img, .twocolumn .right img` using the comma. That seems like the best solution for sure. Thanks!